# R - How to create a new list from elements in a list?

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply, sapply

Say I have a list, `preds`, that contains 3 different sets of predictions based on unique models.

```
set.seed(206)
preds <- list(rnorm(1:100), rnorm(1:100), rnorm(1:100))
```

I am having trouble iterating through the list and creating a new list.  I want a list of new vectors that are composed of the corresponding index in the other vectors.  So for example, I can get the first element in each vector of the list using `sapply()` like this:

```
sapply(preds, "[[", 1)
```

Which works well, but I cannot figure out how to iterate through each element in each vector to construct a new list.  I want something like this (doesn't work):

```
sapply(preds, "[[", 1:100)
```

Using the above seed and `preds` list, my desired output would be something like:

```
first_element <- sapply(preds, "[[", 1)
second_element <- sapply(preds, "[[", 2)
third_element <- sapply(preds, "[[", 3)
desired_result <- rbind(first_element, second_element, third_element)
```

But for all elements in the list, which in this example is 100.

Please let me know if this is not clear, and I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to use `[`

```
res <- sapply(preds, `[`, 1:3 )
all.equal(res, desired_result, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach:

```
nth_element <- function(dat, n){

   res <- sapply(dat, "[[", n)

   res

}

res2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(c(1:3), function(x) nth_element(dat = preds, n = x)))
```

Borrowing akrun's check code:

```
all.equal(res2, desired_result, check.attributes=FALSE)
```

Comment: Very nice, this is where my mind was originally going, but I didn't quite get there.  I had basically identical code but was trying a for() loop instead of just creating a custom function.  I appreciate the additional solution.